# input textbox unfocus-able through 'mousedown'

Tags: javascript, html, select, input, focus

I can't set the focus on the input box through the 'mousedown' event from the canvas but I can do this with 'mouseup', why is that the case? Is this browser specific?(using chrome)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('can');

 canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e)=>{
    document.getElementById('box').focus();
 })
```

```html
<canvas id="can"></canvas>
<input type="text" id="box"></input>
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('can');

 canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', (e)=>{
    document.getElementById('box').focus();
 })
```

```html
<canvas id="can"></canvas>
<input type="text" id="box"></input>
```

I have also fooled around with tabindex(tabindex='-1','0' or '1') but that doesn't work either for **mousedown**. So is my only option to use **mouseup** for this event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't this textarea focusing with .focus()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380759/why-isnt-this-textarea-focusing-with-focus)

Comment: ^ it's due to the order in which focus gets applied. `mousedown` -> `focus` -> `mouseup` -> `click`. Essentially, the element gets focus, then immediately loses it.