# How to check textarea is focus or not?

Tags: angular6

I can't check textarea is focused or not. I'll try with following code but it does't work.

```
    const msg_area = document.getElementById('msg-area') as HTMLInputElement;
    if (msg-area.hasFocus()) {
        // somecode
    }
```

But it doesnot work. There was an error that hasFocus() not found.
hasFocus() not a property of HtmlInputElement.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please read [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't this textarea focusing with .focus()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380759/why-isnt-this-textarea-focusing-with-focus)

Comment: You have a typo in your code, it should be `if (msg_area.hasFocus())`

Comment: I'll try but it not works.